# Pre.intervention and post.intervention should be contiguous in CausalImpact?

Tags: r, causality, causalimpact

I am running a CausalImpact analysis on a time series and my pre.period goes from 01.01.15 to 30.03.15. I want my post period to be from 15.04.15 to 17.04.15.

Is it ok if I create a time series that ignore the gap and just goes from 01.01.05 to 30.03.15 + from 15.04.15 to 17.04.15 (for a total of 3 months and 3 days)?

I am afraid I might obtain wrong results if CausalImpact take the data as continuous while in reality there is a gap of 15 days between them.

Comment: I have never hear of CausualImpact, and I imagine that many reviewers are in the same camp. What kind of time series model are you fitting?

Answer (score 0):

CausalImpact just performs a cross-correlation of residuals from ARIMA models, with some super beefy (unwarranted) cause-y language thrown on top. Depending on the shape or form of the intervention (like in the case of constant additive effect), you probably won't have a powerful analysis. The approach is just not smart enough to find a lag that best aligns the residuals. To fix this, you can just shift the time series yourself, but be warned this kind of post-processing compromises the validity of statistical analysis. For instance, how could I or any external reviewer trust that the number of lagged days that you tweaked was on the basis of prespecified hypotheses and not "what made the analysis most statistically significant"?

Comment: Thanks AdamO, can I ask you some clarifications?

In my case, I want the system to learn during a pre.period (1.01.15 to 30.03.15) and analyse the impact of events that occur only on single days (14.04.15 in the example) on a 3 day-post.period (15.04.15 to 17.04.15). To do so, I run CausalImpact as many times as the events I want to analyse, starting from the event on the 31.03.15 (the day immediately after the pre.period). I create a different dataset each time, made of the unchanged first 90 days of pre.period and of the 3 days of the post.period after single event

Does this make sense?

Comment: @Alfredo hard to say. You may post another question. Add graphs, sample data, anything to make your points clearer. Sounds like you should just a simple t-test.